# Python Tkinter error and installing difficulties

Tags: python, tkinter, terminal

I'm a new coder and was following a tkinter tutorial. I instantly ran into a problem of "Tk not defined." I thought this was because of me not having tkinter installed on my python (my ver is 3.12) so I went to install it via my terminal via the command "pip install tk" but for some reason was greeted with the error Tk is not defined. At this point i'm just confused. Can anyone help?

I keep having the same problem and am facing the same problem.

Comment: `pip install tk` installs tensorkit, not tkinter. You can't install tkinter with pip.

Comment: It is better to post a [mre] and the full error traceback.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.